# ¿Cómo decodificar el caracter ñ correctamente un JSON?

Tags: python, json, flask

Tengo una API en flask y en el siguiente endpoint en concreto,

```
@app.route('/api/method', methods=['POST'])
def api_m():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_data = {}
        data = request.get_json()
```

Al ejecutar un curl estoy intentando enviar el json y tengo que enviar un string que puede contener Ñ para ser procesado.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d "{\"string\":\"aaaaaaAÑ\"}" http://localhost:5000/api/method
```

Al intentar hacerlo estoy teniendo un error de decodificación del JSON ya que no acepta el carácter ñ ¿Qué solución puedo tomar?

```
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: &#x27;utf-8&#x27; codec can&#x27;t decode byte 0xd1 in position 18: invalid continuation byte</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema no lo tienes en la parte python, sino que es culpa de la terminal desde la que estás lanzando el comando `curl`. Me explico.

En el comando `curl` estás especificando `charset=utf-8` como parte de la cabecera `Content-Type`. En el lado python se usará esa cabecera para determinar qué codificacion ha seguido el cliente para el contenido del mensaje. Ya que la cabecera dice que es utf8, ese encoding se intentará. Pero está fallando. Eso indicaría entonces que el contenido del cuerpo realmente enviado en el POST no ha sido utf8.

En efecto, el mensaje de error muestra un problema con un byte de valor 0xd1. Ese código no es válido bajo utf8, pero en cambio puede comprobarse que 0xd1 corresponde a la letra Ñ en el [encoding ISO-8859-1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (también conocido como Latin1). También podría tratarse del encoding ISO-8859-15 (conocido como Latin9), o del cp1252 (utilizado por Windows). En todo caso, no es utf-8

Y es la terminal desde la que estás lanzando `curl` la que está usando ese *encoding*. Tienes por tanto varias soluciones a este problema:

1. Averigua cómo cambiar el encoding de esa terminal para que use utf8
2. Cambia en la cabecera `Content-Type` el encoding para que ponga el que esté usando la terminal (puedes probar`charset=iso-8859-1` y seguramente funcionará)
3. No pases el contenido del json desde línea de comandos para evitar que la terminal interfiera. En cambio, guárdalo en un fichero (asegúrate de que el editor lo guarda como utf8) y usa la opción `-d @nombre_del_fichero` para que curl lo tome de ahí.

Creo que la tercera opción sería la mejor, por ser la más general y evitar que la solución dependa de la terminal usada.